# Do I need to do a PCI Survey

Tags: pci-dss

We are using standalone payment terminals (Ingenico ICT220) over IP and our payment processor (heartland) insists we don't need to do any PCI SAQ or get scanning, they insist they will indemnify us if there's a breach. I can't find any instance of this, it looks to me like I should be doing SAQ B-IP in this instance and a security scan

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with this particular setup from Heartland, but it *sounds* like a "P2PE" solution. In that setup, the payment terminals have special Heartland-specific encryption keys loaded into them before they're shipped, and they encrypt all card data such that Heartland is the only one who can decrypt it. Since the data never transverses your network in a readable form, you're not in PCI scope - not even SAQ B-IP.

That said, there *is* a SAQ P2PE, which basically requires you to attest that you are using a P2PE certified solution and not storing card data in any other way.  You can read about it [here](http://blog.securitymetrics.com/2017/06/a-quick-look-at-saq-p2pe-reducing-PCI-workload.html?m=1) and find the actual document [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2-SAQ-P2PE.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As Heartland (they are your acquirer and so responsible for the card schemes for your compliance) say they don't require anything from you and will indemnify you in the event of a card scheme penalty you should do no more -- as long as they have put this in writing. Only a QSA audit gives you safe harbor from card scheme penalties (not an SAQ) and so the indemnity that Heartland offers is as good to you as an audit. Be happy with this.